# searching for tweets from multiple users with api 1.1

Tags: ios, api, twitter

Ever since I upgraded to api 1.1, I am unable to search for tweets from multiple users.  For example this search-[https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from:commute_by_bike OR from:BikeLeague OR from:peopleforbikes OR from:bikesbelong &count=20](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3acommute_by_bike%20OR%20from%3aBikeLeague%20OR%20from%3apeopleforbikes%20OR%20from%3abikesbelong%20&count=20) returns zero tweets.  This worked previously with the 1.0 api.  If I search for just one of these users, I get the corrects results so I know the authentication is working.  Any suggestions?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the query you post above and using the following curl command (which I got from Twitter's OAuth tool), and I get several tweet results back. Your actual query does work, there is probably just a problem with the formatting somewhere. Retry your query using the OAuth tool to troubleshoot out any formatting problems, then edit your query.

```
curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json' \
--data 'count=20&q=from%3Acommute_by_bike+OR+from%3ABikeLeague+OR+from%3Apeopleforbikes+OR+from%3Abikesbelong+' \
--header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXX", oauth_nonce="XXXXXXXX", oauth_signature="XXXXXXXX", oauth_signature_method="XXXXXXX", oauth_timestamp="XXXXXXXXX", oauth_token="XXXXXXXX", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new 1.1 api, I'm searching for a hashtag with the following line of code:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%%23%@&result_type=mixed", hashtag]
```

Where hashtag is an NSString, not containing the #. You need authentication for that, but you mentioned that the authentication works. Good luck!